# How to exclude processing of certain tags in Magickwand stripimage

Tags: go, exif, magickwand

How to exclude processing of certain tags in Magickwand stripimage function in Go?

https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick#MagickWand.StripImage

Need to exclude value of "Orientation" tag in Exif Metadata but erase another information.